# Test Driven unit testing with stored procedure in VS 2010

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, data-driven-tests

I have a class (Not (DAL)) that get's data from DB and give it to me in required format(in specific class format).

Now i need to write a unit test case, but TestContext Data row always return me single row.

I want to fill TestContext by my stored procedure. Please tell me how can i specify stored procedure name. 
Thanks in advance.

Here  Is Code.

```
public static List<TextValueField> ExternalDataGet(int providerId)
    {
        return ListFactory<TextValueField>.Create(Keys.QAT, "[stats].[GetExternalDataV2]", new object[] { providerId }, TextValueField.Factory);
    }
public static List<T> Create(string key, string sp, object[] parameters, FactoryDelegate factory)
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(key);
        string connectionString = db.ConnectionStringWithoutCredentials;

        using (DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sp, parameters))
        {
            try
            {
                using (cmd.Connection = db.CreateConnection())
                {
                    cmd.Connection.Open();
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    using (DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                                list.Add(factory(reader));
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            if (!reader.IsClosed)   
                                reader.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    cmd.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw new DataAccessException(ex, key, connectionString, sp, parameters);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cmd.Connection != null)
                    if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                        cmd.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: How do i test a method that return DataSet depending upon the argument supplied. please give me some idea.

Comment: You may need to post some code to clarify you question.

Comment: [stats].[GetExternalDataV2] is the name of stored procedure

Comment: I am waiting for your response

Answer (score 0):

> I want to fill TestContext by my stored procedure. Please tell me how can i specify stored procedure name.

This should handle your request.

```
public static List<TextValueField> ExternalDataGet(int providerId, string storedProc = "[stats].[GetExternalDataV2]")
{
    return ListFactory<TextValueField>.Create(Keys.QAT, storedProc, new object[] { providerId }, TextValueField.Factory);
}
```

Comment: I am waiting for your response.

Comment: @PavanTiwari:  Response to what?

Comment: you answer of above question if u have.

Comment: @PavanTiwari:  You haven't asked a question.

Comment: How does i fill my TestContext with the result of Stored Procedure Data

Comment: @PavanTiwari:  Where is TestContext referenced in any of the supplied code?